# Magento 2 : Payment Method Restriction Through Event payment_method_is_active in Admin

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have migrated this piece of code from Magento1 to Magento2.

I am facing problem right now is "Do not know to return the result which we have in array" on admin payment.

Code is:

```
<?php

namespace Getsquare\AdminPayments\Observer\Payment;

class MethodIsActive implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $methodInstance = $observer->getEvent();
        $paymentMethod = $methodInstance->getMethodInstance();
        $config = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sales/getsquare/adminpayments', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $paymentMethod->getStore());
        if (!$config) {
            return;
        }
        $result = $observer->getResult();
        /*print_r($result);*/
        $adminPayments = explode(',', $config);
        if (in_array($paymentMethod->getCode(), $adminPayments) && false == $result->isAvailable) {
            $result->isAvailable = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps me to resolve the problem. 
URL : https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to create **events.xml** file under `app/code/Company/Module/etc/`. Then write **“payment_method_is_active”** event in it. This is the event which hits on checkout page for payment method availability.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create **PaymentMethodAvailable.php** under `Company/Module/Observer/` and write following code in the file. I am disabling the **check money order payment** method, you can change payment method code according to your need.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // you can replace "checkmo" with your required payment method code
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="checkmo"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
}
```

Now the payment method **Check Money Order** is disabled from checkout page .

Hope this blog will help you to develop custom functionality in your module in a better way. Try this and if you have any query then just comment below

Source: [Disable payment method programmatically in Magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/)

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/324813/57334 thanks @mahmoudismail